# Using rails console error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console

I have Produtor model on my app and I'm trying to debug it with rails console..

but when I try to use rails console inside my app directory I get this error

```
D:\ruby\app>rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.9)
irb(main):001:0> Produtors.all
NameError: uninitialized constant Produtors
        from (irb):1
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the name of the model, `Produtor` instead. The extra s is what is throwing you off. Try `Produtor.all` instead.